# cannot sniff the packet going through openwrt network bridge

Tags: openwrt

What I am doing is setting up a spare openwrt as a packet sniffer.

I have setup like this:
[image]

From MY PC, I am using wireshark to capture any packet going through the target board. Currently, my home router IP is 10.10.10.1, my PC is 10.10.10.50 and the openwrt bridge is 10.10.10.80 and my target board is up and has the 10.10.10.28

Using wireshark to observe the openwrt, I can see packet of the 10.10.10.80 but not anything from 10.10.10.28. I have tried using my PC to ping the 10.10.10.28, and I can see that there is the traffic going from my pc to 10.10.10.28 while there is not any captured traffic from 10.10.10.28. Do I setup the OpenWRT wrongly?

I can confirm that the Target device is up and running smoothly, I have run application on it. I just cannot sniff the packet from it for debugging. All the setup is wired network.

Edit: My home router is the gateway and it is running DHCP, the OpenWRT bridge is the DHCP client of the home router. The OpenWRT is connected has one port connected to home router, and one port connected with my Target board (also the dhcp client of my home router). On the Openwrt, I installed tcpdump and I want to capture the port connected with the Target board.
Yes, the ping working but I cannot get all the traffic.

Edit 2: May be am overcareful, my net work is just 10.10.10.1/24. the reason that I place the target board and me is at separated room lmao.
The OpenWRT device is EspresssoBin V5, I am flashing the  OpenWrt 19.07.4.

Edit 3:
I attached the dump from `ip link` in Openwrt

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 532
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:03:83:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wan@eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:03:83:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: lan0@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-bridge state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:03:83:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: lan1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-bridge state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:03:83:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: br-bridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:03:83:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@OpenWrt:~#
```

lan 0 is connected to my target device, lan1 is connected to my home router.

and from `ip -br address`

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip -br address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
eth0             UP             
wan@eth0         LOWERLAYERDOWN 
lan0@eth0        UP             
lan1@eth0        UP             
br-bridge        UP             10.10.10.80/24 fdbd:8391:18c0::1/60 fe80::f2ad:4eff:fe03:83ee/64 
root@OpenWrt:~#
```

***Edit 5: Solution***
*I have found a solution on (this link)[https://forum.openwrt.org/t/passive-tap-hub-and-ethernet-bridge/51178/21]. I am not the expert in networking and OpenWrt, so I left the explanation to the expert. I short, after applying these 2 line, I can see the traffic from my target hardware, but as I said, I don't know the reason why it works.*

```
# bridge vlan add vid 200 dev lan1 pvid untagged master
# bridge vlan add vid 100 dev lan0 pvid untagged master
```

Comment: I do not understand your network set-up. Are all devices connected to a singel switch (same L2 network)? Or are you using the same subnet on both sides of the home router?And the same question for the openwrt?

Comment: Are you meaning that your ping gets no reply, in such case you are trying to fix a network setup, or are you meaning that despite ping working, you can't capture all of its traffic?

Comment: I have edited the description. and yes, the ping working but I can't capture any traffic via openwrt running tcpdump.

Comment: There are so many reasons... Anyway you shouldn't obfuscate private IP addresses. Probably not relevant, but I don't get why the PC isn't connected to the bridge too, or is the router having its own bridge (multiple ports)? If your OpenWRT device is using hardware accelerated bridge (switchdev, "dsa" ...) then it's possible you are not capturing at the right place. Seems you'll have to provide everything possible about your OpenWRT device, including brand/product name, the full tcpdump command and capture samples (eg: you should see from time to time ARP requests because those are broadcasts).

Comment: @A.B Thanks for your help. you are right that I can see the broadcast packet, but not the ping packet. Hmm, I have just read about the HW accelerated you mentioned, it seems that the EspressoBin has a HW switch. Do you have any suggestion on what I need to look at?

Comment: I don't have such device so don't have experience about it. Doc about switchdev: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/switchdev.txt . For anything else you'd still have to provide information I thought would be provided (and that Ljm Dullaart also asked) how is the pc connected? The way to know this is to know all Ip addresses. Then you have to provide a tcpdump capture with the exact command used as typed. Then information about interfaces on the EspressoBin, like `ip link` and also `ip -br address`.

Comment: I think my image can show how the setup looks like. Regarding the tcpdump command, I am not 100% sure, because I use the sshdump inteface of wireshark, which is the wrapper of tcpdump, in the sshdump page, it indicate that the tcpdump command is "tcpdump -U -i br-bridge -w -".

Comment: Capture on the bridge *ports*: lan0 and lan1, instead of the bridge interface. Because of acceleration this might work differently than a pure software bridge anyway.

Comment: I think I have found some work solution. I can confirm that the whether it is the br-bridge, lan0 or lan1, I cannot snip the packet going directly to/from the 10.10.10.28. It seems that these packets were bypassed by the CPU. I have found a discussion on this link https://forum.openwrt.org/t/passive-tap-hub-and-ethernet-bridge/51178/21 , after applying these 2 line, I can see the ping traffic from 10.10.10.28 # bridge vlan add vid 200 dev lan1 pvid untagged master
# bridge vlan add vid 100 dev lan0 pvid untagged master)